# how to make prev and next button working here

Tags: javascript, css, slider

I am using this java script logo slider and I want to make this `prev` and next working. when click on `prev` text slider goes move to left and when click on next it goes to right side.

Working Demo [Here](https://codepen.io/Balvant_Ahir/pen/JBOdVQ).

I am little new to java script i appreciate your help

Code is here:-

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.customer-logos').slick({
      slidesToShow: 6,
      slidesToScroll: 1,
      autoplay: true,
      autoplaySpeed: 1500,
      arrows: false,
      dots: false,
      pauseOnHover: false,
      responsive: [{
          breakpoint: 768,
          settings: {
              slidesToShow: 4
          }
      }, {
          breakpoint: 520,
          settings: {
              slidesToShow: 3
          }
      }]
  });
});
```

```css
h2{
  text-align:center;
  padding: 20px;
}

/* Slider */
.slick-slide {
    margin: 0px 20px;
}

.slick-slide img {
    width: 100%;
}

.slick-slider {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -ms-touch-action: pan-y;
    touch-action: pan-y;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
}

.slick-list {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.slick-list:focus {
    outline: none;
}
.slick-list.dragging {
    cursor: pointer;
    cursor: hand;
}

.slick-slider .slick-track,
.slick-slider .slick-list {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
       -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
        -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
         -o-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
            transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

.slick-track {
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: block;
}
.slick-track:before,
.slick-track:after {
    display: table;
    content: '';
}
.slick-track:after {
    clear: both;
}
.slick-loading .slick-track {
    visibility: hidden;
}

.slick-slide {
    display: none;
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 1px;
}
[dir='rtl'] .slick-slide {
    float: right;
}
.slick-slide img {
    display: block;
}
.slick-slide.slick-loading img {
    display: none;
}
.slick-slide.dragging img {
    pointer-events: none;
}
.slick-initialized .slick-slide {
    display: block;
}
.slick-loading .slick-slide {
    visibility: hidden;
}
.slick-vertical .slick-slide {
    display: block;
    height: auto;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
}
.slick-arrow.slick-hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="container">
   <section class="customer-logos slider">
      <div class="slide"><img src="https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/luxury-letter-e-logo-design_1017-8903.jpg"></div>
      <div class="slide"><img src="https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/3d-box-logo_1103-876.jpg"></div>
      <div class="slide"><img src="https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/blue-tech-logo_1103-822.jpg"></div>
      <div class="slide"><img src="https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/colors-curl-logo-template_23-2147536125.jpg"></div>
      <div class="slide"><img src="https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/abstract-cross-logo_23-2147536124.jpg"></div>
      <div class="slide"><img src="https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/football-logo-background_1195-244.jpg"></div>
      <div class="slide"><img src="https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/background-of-spots-halftone_1035-3847.jpg"></div>
      <div class="slide"><img src="https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/retro-label-on-rustic-background_82147503374.jpg"></div>
   </section>
</div>

<p>prev</p>
<p>next</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why you add `prev` and `next` button in you code when Slick slider already give to you.

Just remove that and In Js replace this: `arrows: true`

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.customer-logos').slick({
        slidesToShow: 6,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        autoplay: true,
        autoplaySpeed: 1500,
        arrows: true, //here change
        dots: false,
        pauseOnHover: false,
        responsive: [{
            breakpoint: 768,
            settings: {
                slidesToShow: 4
            }
        }, {
            breakpoint: 520,
            settings: {
                slidesToShow: 3
            }
        }]
    });
});
```

```css
h2{
  text-align:center;
  padding: 20px;
}
/* Slider */

.slick-slide {
    margin: 0px 20px;
}

.slick-slide img {
    width: 100%;
}

.slick-slider {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -ms-touch-action: pan-y;
    touch-action: pan-y;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
}

.slick-list {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.slick-list:focus {
    outline: none;
}
.slick-list.dragging {
    cursor: pointer;
    cursor: hand;
}

.slick-slider .slick-track,
.slick-slider .slick-list {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -o-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

.slick-track {
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: block;
}
.slick-track:before,
.slick-track:after {
    display: table;
    content: '';
}
.slick-track:after {
    clear: both;
}
.slick-loading .slick-track {
    visibility: hidden;
}

.slick-slide {
    display: none;
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 1px;
}
[dir='rtl'] .slick-slide {
    float: right;
}
.slick-slide img {
    display: block;
}
.slick-slide.slick-loading img {
    display: none;
}
.slick-slide.dragging img {
    pointer-events: none;
}
.slick-initialized .slick-slide {
    display: block;
}
.slick-loading .slick-slide {
    visibility: hidden;
}
.slick-vertical .slick-slide {
    display: block;
    height: auto;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
}
.slick-arrow.slick-hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="container">
   <section class="customer-logos slider">
      <div class="slide"><img src="https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/luxury-letter-e-logo-design_1017-8903.jpg"></div>
      <div class="slide"><img src="https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/3d-box-logo_1103-876.jpg"></div>
      <div class="slide"><img src="https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/blue-tech-logo_1103-822.jpg"></div>
      <div class="slide"><img src="https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/colors-curl-logo-template_23-2147536125.jpg"></div>
      <div class="slide"><img src="https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/abstract-cross-logo_23-2147536124.jpg"></div>
      <div class="slide"><img src="https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/football-logo-background_1195-244.jpg"></div>
      <div class="slide"><img src="https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/background-of-spots-halftone_1035-3847.jpg"></div>
      <div class="slide"><img src="https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/retro-label-on-rustic-background_82147503374.jpg"></div>
   </section>
</div>
```

Updated codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XBzmmG